# Calculate newHeight from children within absolute element

Tags: jquery

I am no programmer so I'm sure this can be answered rather easily:

How can I alter this jQuery script to either:

1. Divide the new height by 2

AND/OR

1. Only calculate the height of the first element inside of the div?

   ```
   $( document ).ready(function() {
       $( "#left-sidebar-inner" ).each(function() {
           var newHeight = 0, $this = $( this );

           $.each( $this.children(), function() {
               newHeight += $( this ).height();
           });

           $this.height( newHeight );
       });
   });
   ```

Both answers would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why `$this = $( this );` what's wrong with just using `$(this);`??

Comment: Also are you sure that all that all the children influence the height of the `div`? You might end up with wrong calculation.

Comment: All the children influence the height, yes, they are just li's in a navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#left-sidebar-inner").each(function () {
        var newHeight = 0,
        $this = $(this);
        $.each($this.children(), function () {
            newHeight += $(this).height();
        });
        $this.height(Math.round( newHeight / 2) );
    });
});
```

not sure what you mean about the second part you would have to post the corresponding html

Comment: I knew it would that simple, thanks! The script works the way I wanted it to, though I have two elements within the div, one in which is set to display:none, though the script is still calculating the height for both. Down the line, there may even be more elements, so the height will still be quite large, therefore, if the script could only calculate the height of the FIRST element and not whatever is after it, that would be even better.

Comment: if itw orked for you please click on the checkmark on the left side to indicate it was the right answer. thanks!

Comment: It's not bad to use `Math.round( $this.height(newHeight / 2) );` you might and up with a float

Comment: Seems to working right, thanks! So you think replacing $this.height(Math.round( newHeight / 2) ); with Math.round( $this.height(newHeight / 2) ); will work better?

Comment: it's not a big deal but no you would do the above which i edited $this.height(Math.round( newHeight / 2) );

Comment: Hmmm...it seems like on Refresh, that it doesn't use the height of the second element...like the display:none works only on refresh. So it halves it correctly. The best bet would be for the script to only calculate the first element in the div.

Comment: From this page: http://martyregan.com/conc/

There are two menus in the left column. The English one loads by default, and the Japanese one is set to display:none by a script. They are both absolute on top of each other. In the right corner, you can swap the menus. The problem was the the div around them (#left-sidebar-inner) didn't know what height it should be, so the background image behind them would be cut off. So with refresh, it only works half the time. If this script only calculated the height of the English menu from it's children, and not both menus, it should work every time, no?